# How to get access to public field from model attribute

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I need to render HTML with a form and I have the following HTML page:

```
<form action="add" th:object="${form} method="post">
   <fieldset>
       <table>
           <tr th:each="book, itemStat : *{books}">
                <td><input th:field="*{books[__${itemStat.index}__].name}" />
           </tr>
       </table>
   </fieldset>
</form>
```

and I have a server-side code:

```
@GetMapping("/add")
public String addBook(Model model) {
    BooksForm form = new BooksForm();
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        form.books.add(new Book());
    }
    model.addAttribute("form", form);
    return "add_books";
}
public class Book {
    public int id;
    public String name;
}
public class BooksForm {
    public List<Book> books = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

but when I try to run this code I get an exception like the following:

```
org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'books[0]' of bean class [com.examples.model.BooksForm]: Bean property 'books[0]' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.getPropertyValue(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:622) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.getNestedPropertyAccessor(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:839) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.getPropertyAccessorForPropertyPath(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:816) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.getPropertyValue
```

but if I adding getter for my public property `public List<Book> books` all is working fine.
Why I couldn't get this property without a getter?

Comment: from your stack trace you already have your answer => somewhere in that AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor spring is trying to find the getter of that property and then complains it cannot find it. If you are really curious put a breakpoint there and try to understand how the framework works, check the callstack etc :)

Comment: I saw this stack trace and I don't understand why I have to add getters to public properties and I thought if anyone faced the same issue, he could help me. But thanks anyway for trying to help.